# Set protocol for go mod download command

Tags: git, go, azure-devops

I've a *go* library, the source for which resides in a private repository (Azure DevOps git). Another *go* project references this library as a dependency. The referenced module path has a VCS qualifier like this:

`dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_git/<repo>.git`

I set the GOPRIAVTE to `dev.azure.com/<organization>`. This ensures that the *go* command will download matching modules from version control repositories where they’re developed.

When `go mod download` command is run, it first clones the repository and then zips it. To clone the repo from vcs, it uses the **ssh** instead of **https**. How do I tell the go command to use **https** instead on **ssh** ?

Here is what the doc says:

> If the module path has a VCS qualifier (one of .bzr, .fossil, .git, .hg, .svn) at the end of a path component, the go command will use everything up to that path qualifier as the repository URL. For example, for the module example.com/foo.git/bar, the go command downloads the repository at example.com/foo.git using git, expecting to find the module in the bar subdirectory. The go command will guess the protocol to use based on the protocols supported by the version control tool.

Comment: You cannot. You have to tell this git, e.g. via url insteadof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really a git question, the answer is:

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@your.private.git/.insteadOf https://your.private.git/
```